# How to make a 100% Stacked Chart with 2 measures in Tableau?

Tags: tableau-api

I am using Tableau to create a productivity progress bar of actual work done, versus the goal for that day. I have gone through numerous resources, but none seem to apply to only using 2 measures, basically putting the actual data measure turned into a percent within the goal measure. I have the chart working by using a calculated field of Missed Goal ([Goal]-[Actual]) but I am wanting into to look like a 100% stacked chart. Here is a picture of what I have, I just can't seem to get the last step expanding the bars horizontally to be a %100 chart:

Currently looks like:
[image]

Wanting it to look like:
[image]

Thank you for any help!

Comment: Can you post a picture of what you want it to look like? Also, have you tried clicking on the "Show Me" at the top right and selected 100% chart?

Comment: Added the chart that I am wanting it to look like. And Tabluea doesn't have a 100% option in the "Show Me".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a good candidate for a few [LOD Calculated Fields](https://onlinehelp.tableau.com/current/pro/desktop/en-us/calculations_calculatedfields_lod.htm).

I will give an example based on the SuperStore dataset where [Profit] is a percentage of [Sales]. This can be extrapolated to your use case.

Because you have two dimensions on the view, both will be needed to be accounted for in the LOD calculations below:

```
//LOD Sales
{Fixed [Segment], Year([Ship Date]): SUM([Sales])} / {Fixed [Segment], Year([Ship Date]): SUM([Sales])}
```

We will always want [LOD Sales] to equal 1 for bar-chart display purposes.

```
//LOD Profit
{fixed [Segment], Year([Ship Date]): SUM([Profit])} / {Fixed [Segment], Year([Ship Date]): SUM([Sales])}
```

This will create the percentage of [Profit] to [Sales].

From there, you'll want to turn off Stack Marks so the bars overlap eachother:

```
Analysis Menu > Stack Marks > Off
```

And probably change the axis display to a percentage:

```
Right click [Measure Values] > Default Properties > Number Format > Percentage
```

For simplicity, your existing filters should be placed 'On Context' as to not interfere with the LODs. (Please read above linked article for reasoning and alternatives.)

```
Right click on Filtered Field > Add to Context
```

The end result should look like this:

[image]

Comment: Thank you, that worked perfectly! Is there a way to still have the actual values show when the bars are hovered over instead of a percentage? For example, showing 400 out of a bar of 500 instead of 80% out of 100%?

Comment: Great to hear. With regard to displaying actual - the closest you'll probably be able to get is to display both of them on a tooltip. Dragging SUM(Actual) and SUM(Goal Missed) to tooltip. Unstacking marks makes things a bit more difficult to display. (ie Note that all labels are applied to the top of the bar instead of in the bar)